# Timestamp difference of single day from Fisrt insert and last insert of same date

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

Below is the Query

```
SELECT
cap_newspaper_page.capnewspaperID,
cap_newspaper_page.capnewspaperPageID,
cap_newspaper.newspaperStationID,
cap_newspaper_page.insertDate
FROM
cap_newspaper_page
```

I write a query which result is given below!
but problem is that I want a time difference total for every single day. Like I want total duration of 27 of June and also for other dates. Please help me out for this query.

[image]

```
I want Time difference from -2012-06-27 18:54:27- To -2012-06-27 19:26:58-
and respectively for other dates!
```

[Click Here for **LARGER IMAGE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju0we.png)

Answer (score 2):

you could use date_diff.

Save your dates into a variable.
Then, if you are comparing all to today,

```
    $insert_date=$sql['insertDate'];
    $now = date_create("now");
$compDate = date_create(date($insert_date));
$interval = date_diff($compDate,$now);
```

edit:
if you are running a while loop to display your data - you could simply use an array to hold the time from each record, then you can display the time based on the difference between the two you wish to use.

If I'm understanding you correctly, it would be similar to this;

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
$i=$i+1;
$insert_date[$i] = $row['insertDate'];
if ($i!=0){
$interval = date_diff($insert_date[$i],$insert_date[$i-1]);
}
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['insertDate'] . "</td><td>" . $interval . "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Still I didnt found my Answer. I think that a loop in month will be written to take the Time from first inserDate and last insertDate with in the same date. like 2012-06-27 18:54:27-To-2012-06-27 19:26:58
(19:26:58-18:54:27=01:17:31)

Comment: I edited my response to give a better description of the answer.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
cap_newspaper_page.capnewspaperID,
cap_newspaper_page.capnewspaperPageID,
cap_newspaper.newspaperStationID,
(select sum(TIME(cap_newspaper_page.insertDate)) from cap_newspaper_page a where DATE(a.insertDate) = DATE(b.insertDate)
group by DATE(a.insertDate))
FROM
cap_newspaper_page b
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this one works:

```
SELECT
IF(@tmpDate != DATE(q.insertDate), @firstDate := DATE(q.insertDate), @firstDate := @firstDate) as seeIfDateChanged, @tmpDate := q.insertDate, q.*, TIMEDIFF(q.insertDate, @firstDate) AS timeDifference
FROM (
SELECT
*
FROM
yourTable yt
, (SELECT @firstDate:=NULL, @tmpDate:=NULL) r
ORDER BY insertDate
) q
```